# Passing Image of ImagePickerView in another View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimage, uistoryboardsegue

Hello to everyone in my view controller I'm using imagePickerView

When the user selects a photo from the library I would like the selected photo will be displayed in another view controller .

I'm currently using the storyboard so I'm using this method:

```
- (void) imagePickerController : ( UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo : ( NSDictionary *) info {
        
    UIImage * PhotoForEdit = self.FF_image ;
    PhotoForEdit = [info objectForKey : UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage ] ;
    
   FFEditingPhotoPost *VCPhotoEdit = [[FFEditingPhotoPost alloc] initWithImage:PhotoForEdit];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"immagine"sender:self];  
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:VCPhotoEdit animated:NO];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}





  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
        FFEditingPhotoPost * controller = (FFEditingPhotoPost *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.FFOriginalImage = FF_image;
    }
```

My problem is that I can not go with storyboard image selected in view CONTROLLR next ... Where am I doing wrong ?

Thank you all for the advice

EDIT : insert view controller that should show photo

```
#import "FFEditingPhotoPost.h"
#import "UIImage+Resize.h"

@interface FFEditingPhotoPost ()

@end

@implementation FFEditingPhotoPost
@synthesize FFScrollView;
@synthesize FFImageView;
@synthesize FFOriginalImage;
@synthesize SelectedFoto;
@synthesize SelectedFotoMiniature;



- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        if (!image) {
            return nil;
        }

        FFOriginalImage = image;
       // self.fileUploadBackgroundTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
       // self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FFScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    FFScrollView.delegate = self;
    FFScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   // self.view = FFScrollView;

    FFImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 42.0f, 280.0f, 280.0f)];
    [FFImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [FFImageView setImage:FFOriginalImage];
    [FFImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    FFImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    FFImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    FFImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.0f);
    FFImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    FFImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;


    [FFScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(FFScrollView.bounds.size.width, FFImageView.frame.origin.y + FFImageView.frame.size.height + FFImageView.frame.size.height)];

    [self shouldUploadImage:FFOriginalImage];

}
- (BOOL)shouldUploadImage:(UIImage *)anImage {
    UIImage *resizedImage = [anImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:CGSizeMake(560.0f, 560.0f) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [anImage thumbnailImage:86.0f transparentBorder:0.0f cornerRadius:10.0f interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];

    // JPEG to decrease file size and enable faster uploads & downloads
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.8f);
    NSData *thumbnailImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnailImage);

    if (!imageData || !thumbnailImageData) {
        return NO;
    }

    SelectedFoto = [PFFile fileWithData:imageData];
    SelectedFotoMiniature = [PFFile fileWithData:thumbnailImageData];
       [SelectedFoto saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Photo uploaded successfully");
            [SelectedFotoMiniature saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded) {
                    NSLog(@"Thumbnail uploaded successfully");
                }
            }];
        } else {
        }
    }];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why are pushing the view controller and performing segue operation at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think PhotoForEdit = [info objectForKey : UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage ] ; Should be self.FF_image =

EDIT -----

There are several things wrong with your code. Firstly, you are creating 2 copies of the `FFEditingPhotoPost` view controller. Who knows which one actually ends up on top.

If you have a storyboard segue set up, then change your image picker code to just perform the segue like this:

```
- (void) imagePickerController : ( UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo : ( NSDictionary *) info {

    self.FF_image = [info objectForKey : UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage ] ;

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"immagine"sender:self];

}
```

Your `prepareForSegue` code is fine. Notice I also switched around the code that sets the self.FF_image property as this was the wrong way around.

Now in your `FFEditingPhotoPost` view controller, you don't need the `initWithImage` method, simple use the `viewWillAppear` method to set your image. The `viewDidLoad` method is called before your `prepareForSegue` which means `FFOriginalImage` is nil while you try to use it.

So use `viewWillAppear` like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [FFImageView setImage:FFOriginalImage];
}
```

Comment: Hello Darren and thanks for the reply ... Your advice seems to have worked, the app does not crash and everything is fine but I still do not see the image passed ... I do not understand why ... I edited my post by inserting the view controller that should show photo

Comment: Remove your segue code. You are already allocating the VC and pushing it, so no need for the segue too. The segue also creates a VC so you end up with 2